# categorical_crossentropy expects array of certain size

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to read in a data set of images, and do some processing, i would need to reshape the array how ever i see the error below;

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)

```py
##################LAYER ONE###################
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:])) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))  
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25)) 
###################LAYER ONE###################

###################LAYER TWO###################
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
###################LAYER TWO###################

###################LAYER THREE###################
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
###################LAYER TWO###################

###################LAYER FOUR###################
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
###################LAYER FOUR###################

model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(64)) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))

odel.add(Dense(units = 3 , activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])  

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=30, epochs=200, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[tensorboard]
```

Comment: What's the shape of X and y?

Comment: it seems that your predicted values `y` do not have the required shape. Make sure that you use one-hot encoded array of size (BATCH_SIZE, 3). I guess that 3 is the number of classes that you use.

Comment: I am using 4 classes, i have fixed this by doing the following: y_binary = to_categorical(y), problem is now that no matter my input the cnn always predicts one class